# Javascript HTML5 <audio> multiple source

Tags: javascript, audio, mp3, ogg

I am trying to insert the same song into 2 different sources on my audio player using javascripts 'getElementByID'.

HTML:

```
<audio id="audio">
   <source id="ogg" src="song1.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
   <source id="mp3" src="song2.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
   Your browser does not support the audio tag.
</audio>
```

JavaScript:

```
function songOne(){ 
    document.getElementById('ogg').src="../audio/pt/lllg/Panda's Thumb.ogg";
    document.getElementById('mp3').src="../audio/pt/lllg/Panda's Thumb.mp3";
    document.getElementById('songName').innerHTML="Panda's Thumb";
    audio.play();
}
```

As you can see, when the function runs, it places the .ogg file into the id="ogg" and the .mp3 into the id=".mp3". Though, when I inspect the element the source has changed but the song will not play.

I can get it to work with only one source:

```
<audio id="audio" src=""></audio>
```

But then it will only play on browsers that support mp3 or ogg and the others miss out. 
**What am i doing wrong?**

Comment: according to http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp your mp3 should have `type="audio/mpeg"`

Comment: Thanks for the fix, I have changed this but it hasn't fixed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know much about HTML5 Audio, but try this:

> After you change the **src** attr, issue a `audio.load();` command

Check this article: http://html5doctor.com/native-audio-in-the-browser/

Comment: If i had the rep i'd vote you up good sir. I appreciate the help! I don't know how i let that one pass me.